# Why should MediaPlayer API be declared as global instance variable?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        MediaPlayer mediaN = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.master6);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mediaN.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have intialised a new `MediaPlayer` object within the `onCreate` method. When i want to use the `MediaPlayer` object `mediaN` to call `start()` method, it asks me to declare the object as final. However, I don't get any errors if I initialise `MediaPlayer` object as instance variable of the class `MainActivity`. Why am I asked to make the `MediaPlayer` object as `final` when it is declared as a local variable to `onCreate` method?

Answer (score 0):

Local classes can most definitely reference instance variables. The reason they cannot reference non final local variables is because the local class instance can remain in memory after the method returns. When the method returns the local variables go out of scope, so a copy of them is needed. If the variables weren’t final then the copy of the variable in the method could change, while the copy in the local class didn’t, so they’d be out of sync.
“Anonymous classes in Java and final variables” https://medium.com/@emerino/anonymous-classes-in-java-and-final-variables-1b1830ac480b
This should help.